# SQL: Find records with matching values on a set of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 RD.

I've got the following table say `myTable` consisting of a number of columns. `AccID` and `AccName` are the columns in which I'm interested in and non of them is a primary-key. So I want to obtain all the records having at least a duplicate (there could be more than 2 rows agreeing on `AccID` and `AccName`).

```
  AccID     AccName
1 333       SomeName1
2 333       SomeName1
3 444       SomeName2
4 444       SomeName2
5 444       SomeName2
```

How can I do this with SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select m1.AccID, m1.AccName 
from   myTable m1
join   ( select AccID,AccName 
         from myTable  
         group by AccID,AccName
         having count(1) = 2 
        ) m2 on   m1.AccID   = m2.AccID
             and  m1.AccName =  m2.AccName
```

Comment: I've used your answer substituting `having count(1) = 2` with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` and I upvoted @mhasan thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use GROUP BY clause and COUNT aggregate function with condition specified by

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the records (not just the names of the duplicate values), I would suggest using the `count()` window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by AccID, AccName) as cnt
      from mytable t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: 1+ because it's beautiful :)

Comment: too complicated. a simple group by and having will do.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*
from myTable t
inner join
(
  select AccID, AccName
  from myTable
  group by AccID, AccName
  having count(1) > 1
) agg on t.AccID = agg.AccID and t.AccName = agg.AccName
```